# SwiftUI WidgetKit: How to open specific viewController when app is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I am building widgets for iOS 14 using WidgetKit and would like to open specific `viewControllers` of my app when users tap on different `Links` on the widget. The opening of the app works only when my app is in the background. When the app is terminated, it simply opens the app only.

Here's the expected workflow:

1. User taps on `Links` on widget
2. Opens app (shows `ViewController`, where `ViewController` is the entry VC when users open the app)
3. Present `CameraController`

My current implementation achieved step 3 only when app is in the background. How do I achieve the same result when app is terminated.

Code:

```
//At Widget View
struct CameraWidgetView : View {
    var entry: CameraEntry
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
            
            Link(destination: URL(string: "scheme://camera")!, label: {
                Text("Camera")
            })
        }
        .widgetURL(URL(string: "scheme://camera"))
    }
}

//At my app's SceneDelegate.swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    
    if let item = URLContexts.first {
        let url = item.url

        if "\(url)" == "scheme://camera" {
            let vc = ViewController()
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            
            window?.rootViewController = navController
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            window?.windowScene = windowScene
            
            let cameraController = CameraController()
            let camNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: cameraController)
            navController.present(camNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your appDelegate, implement

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration
```

and there handle your `options.urlContexts`